# Is time complexity O(1) or O(n) if n is known to be bounded to a constant?

Tags: time-complexity

Suppose you have a poker table where the number of seats can be anywhere between 2 and 10. Would an operation of iterating the table's seats be regarded as O(1) operation or O(n) operation?

My guess is that it would be regarded as O(1) since the worst case scenario is 10 iterations, which is a constant, but I am not sure. What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity here will be `O(n)`. Even though it is bounded but still it will depend on `n` and `n` is a variable with the constraint `2 <= n <= 10`.

It would have been `O(1)` if `n` was a constant.